# How to use fingerprint authentication with VM in virtual box on Windows host

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a laptop with fingerprint. It's running Windows 10.

I want to install another Windows in a VM in virtualbox and want to protect the data in that VM of virtualbox.

Virtualbox provides password protection feature for VM. But I want to go passwordless / I want to use the fingerprint of laptop.

How to use this fingerprint authentication for VM?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research with VMware and Hyper-V which I have installed here.

I check the literature on Virtual Box as well.

Here is a a sample below of removable Devices.

For VMware and Hyper-V and then as far as I know for Virtual Box, Fingerprint Reader does not pass through to the guest machines. The fingerprint reader is (at least on my machines) tied into the real BIOS (UEFI) which is not available (in real form) to the Guest machine.

[image: VMware Removable Devices]

.

So you cannot do what you are trying to do. You will need a proper password (and perhaps a PIN) on the Guest machine.